# How to stream video between two iPhones?

Tags: iphone, video, stream, p2p

I'm building an app that streams video in and out between two iPhone clients. The handshake between the iPhones is done by the server, but that's it for the server - the server doesn't do streaming. The streaming is done directly between iphone 1 <-> iphone 2.

How do I create this stream? How do I create the connection? Using the IP of each iphone? Normal url connection?

Comment: @sajwan hi i didn't find a solution but i found this framework: http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/features